# Can I use firestore on different platform at the same time

Tags: php, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working with a system that has two modules one for admin and the other was for the user, I want to use firebase firestore for my database however I'm quite confuse if it is possible for firestore to cater two different platform, for the user I will be using Flutter (mobile) and for the admin system I will be using php (web) Is it possible to access the database for multiple platform on the firestore?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely supported, and in fact quite common, to have apps from different platforms connecting to the same Firebase project.

In your case, you'll [use security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to ensure that the users in the Flutter app can only access data they're authorized for, while the admin system (assuming it uses an Admin SDK) will automatically bypass those security rules.